# Struggling to display a variable in a memo

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am new to programming and I am still struggling, can someone please tell me how I display a variable with a numeric value in a memo. I tried Memo1.Lines.Add(iNum);

Comment: It is often better to include the specific error or misbehavior that you are getting in the question. Providing as much detail as possible about what goes wrong and what you have tried can help avoid answers suggesting solutions that you have already tried.

Answer (score 2):

`Add()` expects a `String` as input.  You can convert an `Integer` to a `String` using the [`IntToStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.IntToStr) function from the `SysUtils` unit:

```
uses
  ..., SysUtils;

Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(iNum));
```